# How to check if a zip / post code starts with instead of includes

Tags: ruby

I'd like some help to work out how to properly use starts_with? to use the below code to hide a sunday shipping rate if the post code starts with one in the list. I've got it to the position where it will hide my sunday rate if the post code INCLUDES one of the values from my list, but not if it STARTS WITH.

I thought I could update the includes to be starts with but I'm not well versed enough to understand where I'm going wrong here as I've only been learning about JS/Ruby for a few weeks.

```
# ============ PostCodeIdentifier ======================== 
class PostCodeIdentifier
  def initialize(code_trigger)
    @codes = code_trigger[:codes].map(&:downcase)
    @trigger_when = code_trigger[:trigger_when].downcase
  end
  def match?(post_code)
    case @trigger_when
    when :matches
      return true if @codes.any? {|code| post_code.downcase.include?(code)}
    when :does_not_match
      return true unless @codes.any? {|code| post_code.downcase.include?(code)}
    else 
      return false
    end
  end
end
# ============ PostCodeHideRateCampaign =================
class PostCodeHideRateCampaign
  def initialize(post_code_triggers)
    @post_code_triggers = post_code_triggers
  end
  def run(cart, shipping_rates)
    return unless cart.shipping_address.zip
    @post_code_triggers.each do |post_code_trigger|
      post_code_identifier = PostCodeIdentifier.new(post_code_trigger)
      if post_code_identifier.match?(cart.shipping_address.zip)
        shipping_rates.delete_if do |rate|
          rate.name.downcase.include?(post_code_trigger[:rate_to_hide_trigger].downcase)
        end
      end
    end
  end
end

# ========================================== DO NOT SHOW ==========================================
POST_CODE_TRIGGERS_1 = [
  {codes: [
     'AB33' , 'AB34' , 'AB35' , 'AB36' , 'AB37' , 'AB38' , 'AB39' , 'AB40' , 'AB41' , 'AB42' , 'AB43' , 'AB44' , 'AB45' , 'AB46' , 'AB47' , 'AB48' , 'AB49'
   ],
  rate_to_hide_trigger: 'SUNDAY',
  trigger_when: :matches },
]


CAMPAIGNS = [
  PostCodeHideRateCampaign.new(
    POST_CODE_TRIGGERS_1
  )
]

CAMPAIGNS.each do |campaign|
 campaign.run(Input.cart, Input.shipping_rates)
end

# ========================================== END POSTCODE RESTRICTIONS ==========================================
```

Tried changing around the includes and matches to start_with? where I thought it would work, but I'm missing something.

Comment: Check what's in `post_code.downcase` and `@codes`.

Comment: Please add some variables with content that match your used cases, and a short piece of code that exercises the logic, and shows the problem that you're encountering.

Comment: (untested) `start_with?` takes multiple arguments, so `post_code.start_with?(*codes.map(&:downcase))` might work. The `*` "splats" the array into multiple arguments. If it works then it should be enough to replace the entire `match?` method.